# Validation before saving object to session

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

I have a Post object that I would like to save to `session[:post].`

In my **Post.rb**, I have:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :link, presence: true, url: true
```

I would like to use this validation before I save my **post object to session** (not database). Is there a way to do that?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
post = Post.new(args)
if post.valid?
  # save to session
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Call the method `post.valid?` on your object before saving it into your session ?